# Run a LLVM Pass without using opt tool

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I am a beginner in writing LLVM Pass, and I was going through the documentation about writing my own LLVM pass and then run it with opt tool, i.e

```
/llvm/bin/opt -load /llvm/lib/LLVMHello.so  -hello input.ll
```

Here, my pass is `Hello.cpp` and a C function is in `input.c` which is converted to `input.ll` by Clang.

My question is can we run our pass without using `opt` tool i.e.

```
./hello input.ll
```

Is there any method to run a pass like above such method?

Comment: if you're just looking for convenience, perhaps a shell script would be adequate?

Comment: opt is dependent on many llvm libraries and in nerd language it is like a nintendo nes console which can use many games' nes cartridges(llvm passes). you can make a independent opt tool binary specific for your pass using api hooks in opt itself and link with llvm libraries, but it is NOT a good design and not worth spending time, but it is upto you, for the start point you can start looking into the tools/opt/CMakeLists.txt for dependencies and source files for api hooks.

Answer (score 1):

After attaining a valid `Module`, for example, via `llvm::parseBitcodeFile`, all actions you need are just creating `llvm::legacy::Passmanager`, invoking `llvm::legacy::Passmanager::add` to add passes and finally invoking `llvm::legacy::Passmanager::run` on your module.

`opt` use a class derived from `llvm::legacy::Passmanager` but actually call methods in the base class to cope with modules.